# Apply javascript with the script tag

Tags: javascript, import, tags

I have a page where users can creates their own script to modify texts on the server (don't worry the access is restricted to a few users). So the users only have three fields they can fill, one with the name of the rule, another with the expression to replace and a last one with what to replace it with:

```
<label id="name">Name: </label> <input type="text" name="ruleName" size="50" id="ruleName"></input> </br>
<label id="input">Replace: </label> <input type="text" size="50" name="inputStep1" id="inputStep1"></input> </br>
<label id="output">By:</label> <input type="text" size="50" id="outputStep1"></input></br>
```

After that the rules are stored in a file on the server via a `php` post (I'll spare you the unecessary details of this command...). and then the rules are listed in a form with checkboxes, and I want that when the checkboxes are clicked the rule is applied.

The only thing I could come up with was to import the script file via a script tag but only by importing it it doesn't run the inside script.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I Dont fully understand your question. are the saved scripts Javascripts? how should the execute(with which arguments)? ...? leaving out unecessary details is good, but i would need smoe more Context to understand what is happening/what should happen. maybe you could help filling in the blanks.

Comment: ..and most important, how can the "rules" look like which are posted?

Comment: I think that he posts a form, then get a list of radio buttons. On select of a radio button, he wants to post the form again. That's what I got from his question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear, I'll try to rephrase it.
I have a user deffined javascript file that is stored on the server that look like this: 1 = document.getElementById('withRules').innerHTML.replace('ccc','ddd');
document.getElementById('withRules').innerHTML =1;
and then I need that when a radio button is selected the content of that file to apply...

Comment: Just wanted to ask if your question is answered?

Comment: @zopa is the question answered. if so please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understund you correct, you would have to create a script file with contentlike this

generate Script on the server:

```
// i would approch this totally differt, because i would not let user generate script on the server, but to answer the question ...
function executeRule(){ // name of the function is probably the Rulename and must be unique
  document.getElementyId("withRules").innHTML = document.getElementyId("withRules").innHTML.replace('[userenteredvalue1]','[userenteredvalue2]');
}
```

//this code should just be executed when the radiobutton is selected

and than i would add the script per html - script - tag

```
<script src="/generated_user_script.js"></script> <!-- a line per generated script -->
```

and than on select(the `onchange`/`onclick` Event, when the `checked` attribute is set) i would call the function, quick an dirty. :)
if you have many rules you need uniqe names, so that they dont override themselfes and so on.

this said an other approche were javascript code is not create would be better. 
If it is only the replace function, may be you could store the input and output values or so.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my biggest problem was to create unique name that made sens because I have a title field, but it would contain some space so I can't use it as a function name...

Comment: You could use the name of the rule, replace whitespaces with Underscores and if you would want to be on the save side you could append a Randomnumber/Timestamp at the end. so that **"Replace A with B"** would create a filename like **"Replace_A_with_B"** or **"Replace_A_with_B_56234356246"** . Is just an idea. :)

Comment: yeah I think that'll do the trick, I'll try and let you know! thanks